# Flutter FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

- Where:
  Build file '\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
> > Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.VersionCheckPlugin

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan
  to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Answer (score 0):

pls share app/build.gradle file,
full stake trace and and flutter doctor output,
you can get full stake trace by running flutter run --verbose

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

Comment: gradle-wrapper.properties FILE
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

Comment: put it somewhere on github and share url so it can be readble,